gcloud commands hanging for abnormal amount of time
I'm using the Google Cloud SDK and gcloud to connect to my company's proxies, databases, etc. Typically, I obtain my access token using: gcloud auth print-identity-token.
However, today this command has been taking an ungodly amount of time to execute, often hanging indefinitely in the terminal.
After examining the logs, I noticed that the delay occurs whenever there is a network connection request or check, as shown here:

It seems that Python's urllib3 library is involved. I'm using Python 3.11.8 and running Manjaro. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling gcloud by following their uninstall guide, but still no good.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

It sounds like your issue might be related to network connectivity or configuration problems that are causing urllib3 to hang when trying to establish a connection. Here are some steps you can take to diagnose and potentially resolve the issue:
1. Check Network Configuration
Ensure that your network settings are correct and that no firewalls or network policies might interfere with the connection. You can try:

Disabling any VPNs or proxies temporarily to see if they are causing the issue.
Checking your /etc/hosts file for any incorrect entries.
Running ping and traceroute commands to see if you can reach the Google Cloud endpoints.

2. Check Python and urllib3
Since urllib3 is involved, ensure that you have the latest versions of Python and urllib3:
`pip install --upgrade urllib3`

If you suspect there might be an issue with your Python environment, you could try using a virtual environment to isolate and manage dependencies:
python -m venv gcloud-env
source gcloud-env/bin/activate
pip install google-cloud-sdk

3. Enable Debug Logging
Enable debug logging for gcloud to get more detailed information about what might be going wrong:
export CLOUDSDK_CORE_LOG_HTTP=True
gcloud auth print-identity-token

4. Check Proxy Settings
If you are behind a proxy, make sure your proxy settings are configured correctly. You can set the proxy settings in the gcloud configuration:
gcloud config set proxy/address [PROXY_ADDRESS]
gcloud config set proxy/port [PROXY_PORT]

5. Try a Different Network
If possible, try connecting to a different network to see if the issue is network-specific.
By following these steps, you should be able to identify the root cause of the problem and hopefully resolve it. Let me know if you need any more detailed guidance on any of these steps!
